# Angular run function on valid form

Tags: angularjs, forms

is there a way to run a function once a form is valid? like instead of

```
ng-click="doSmtg(userForm.$valid)"
```

just run it once valid without a click. like if there was an ng-run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just

```
<div ng-if="userForm.$valid" ng-init="doSmtg()">
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/e96ceaox/

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question. basically you do ng-if then ng-init which will run once ng-if params are true